# Android layout like Messaging app

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I am trying to create an Android GUI similar to the one used by the stock Android Messaging application.

- An EditText and Button will be anchored to the bottom of the view. The EditText may grow and shrink to show one or more lines of text.  The Button will be placed to the right of the EditText.
- A MvvmCross MvxListView will fill the remaining space. The MvxListView should automatically re-size vertically as the EditText shrinks and grows, or the keyboard is popped up by the user.

I've not been able to come up with something that works exactly as I want. The problem with my current solution is the hardcoded margin. When I put in two lines of text I end up with overlapping views. Does anyone know how I can make the MvxListView grow/shrink to fill the remaining space?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/MessageConversationView_MessageList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Messages" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is `Mvx.MvxListView`?

Comment: I am using C#, MvvmCross, and Xamarin.Android.  Mvx.MvxListView is an MvvmCross ListView control.  MvvmCross is a C# MVVM library for Android, iOS, Windows Phone, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you'd like something like below. Note: I've written this code using Android Studio and a regular `ListView`, i.e. it's not tested for Xamarin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button

            android:text="Send"
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_above="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:id="@+id/MessageConversationView_MessageList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Messages" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Result with a populated list:

[image: Result]

Result when the user enters text:

[image: Result2]

This does work with Xamarin as well.

Comment: Yes, I think you understood what I am looking for. However, that layout cannot be loaded by Xamarin because it has more than one root element.

Comment: Yes that was my bad, I forgot to format it properly. Try now :-) @TrevorBalcom

Comment: It is working now. I see the key difference between your layout and mine is the nesting of a second RelativeLayout, and adding layout_above to the ListView.

Comment: Correct :-) happy coding! @TrevorBalcom